# Convert Chinese Pinyin with accents to numerical form

Tags: php, nlp, cjk

I'm looking to convert Pinyin where the tone marks are written with accents (e.g.: Nín hǎo) to Pinyin written in numerical/ASCII form (e.g.: Nin2 hao1).

Does anyone know of any libraries for this, preferably PHP? Or know Chinese/Pinyin well enough to comment?

I started writing one myself that was rather simple, but I don't speak Chinese and don't fully understand the rules of when words should be split up with a space.

I was able to write a translator that converts:

`Nín hǎo. Wǒ shì zhōng guó rén` ==> `Nin2 hao3. Wo3 shi4 zhong1 guo2 ren2`

But how do you handle words like the following - do they get split up with a space into multiple words, or do you interject the tone numbers within the word (if so, where?) :
`huā shíjiān`, `wèishénme`, `yuèláiyuè`, `shēngbìng`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with parsing pinyin without the space separating each word is that there will be ambiguity. Take, for instance, the name of an ancient Chinese capital [长安](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changan): Cháng'ān (notice the disambiguating apostrophe). If we strip out the apostrophe however this can be interpreted in two ways: `Chán gān` or `Cháng ān`. A Chinese would tell you that the second is far more likely, depending on the context of course, but there's no way your computer can do that.

Assuming no ambiguity, and that all input are valid, the way I would do it would look something like this:

1. Create accent folding function
2. Create an array of valid pinyin (You should take it from the Wikipedia page for pinyin)
3. Match each word to the list of valid pinyin
4. Check ahead to the next word when there is ambiguity about the possibility of the last character belonging to the next word, such as:

```
 shēngbìng
     ^ Does this 'g' belong to the next word?
```

Anyway, the correct positioning of the numerical representation of the tones, and the correct numerals to represent each accent are covered fairly well in this section of the Wikipeda article on pinyin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Numerals_in_place_of_tone_marks. You might also want to have a look at how [IMEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor) do their job.

Comment: I wish I could +2 this for the explanation about ambiguity.

Comment: So would you say to look for the longest syllables first, greedily, as found here: http://pinyin.info/rules/initials_finals.html? So is this correct for the example input I provided (assuming no ambiguity)? `hua1 shi2jian1`, `wei4shen2me5`, `yue4lai2yue4`, and `sheng1bing4` -- basically, injecting numbers in between each of the "syllables" listed, and leaving the spacing as-is?

Comment: 长安 in pinyin is written Cháng'ān specifically to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Spacing should stay the same, but you got numbering of tones incorrectly.
Nin2 hao3. Wo3 shi4 zhong1 guo2 ren2.

wèishénme becomes wei4shen2me.

1. Remove diacritical marks by mapping "āáǎà" to "a", etc.
2. Using simple maximum matching algorithm, split compounds into syllables (there are only 418 or so Mandarin syllables).
3. Append numbers (you have to remember what kind of mark you removed) and joing syllables back into compounds.

Comment: You're right on some of the tone numbers. I've corrected that in my post. But can you elaborate on spacing? In my examples, how should the spacing work? If some words are supposed to have numbers within the word (not just at the end), how do I know where to inject them?

Comment: Excellent explanation -- I extracted 409 from http://pinyin.info/rules/initials_finals.html and will use a greedy algorithm. Are my by-hand answers in a comment on Yi Jiang's answer correct? Lastly, is it wrong to call a "compound" a "word"?

Comment: "Word" is the correct term in this case, because pinyin defines what a word actually is. Sorry for confusion. "Compound" more broadly used for Chinese, because concept of what  word is, is very blurry in the language. Your answers are correct. What you do is just marking tones of the syllables in a different way, in case your font or keyboard don't let you see/type proper pinyin with diacritical marks.